# How to partially animate sprite in Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a large sprite. I want to animate parts of it. Obviously I don't want 30 images of said sprite, I want only the difference, that light blinking or something.

How do I handle that? So far using many images for sprite animations has been way to go for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SKSpriteNode can have children, so you can overlay as many as you like on top of a given SKSpriteNode.

For example if you had a christmas tree, you could put 20 lights on the tree by just adding a child SKSpriteNode for each light and positioning it appropriately. You could then have each of those lights animate independently and dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can create you sprite with something like layering.

In practice it will be looking like sprites (that will be animated separated) under 'big' sprite that you do not want to animate.